# mySQL many-many WHERE conditions no results, cakephp pagination

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am doing a custom pagination rules for CakePHP application. The query created by cake pagination does not return any results and I believe it should.

### The tables are as follows:

```
projects ('id', 'project_leader_id'), 
users ('id', 'name'),
users_projects ('id', 'project_id', 'user_id')

projects many-many users_projects on project_id,
users many-many users_projects on user_id,
users one-many projects on project_leader_id
```

### Sample data:

projects:

```
id (1), project_leader_id (1) 
id (2), project_leader_id (2)
id (3), project_leader_id (3)
```

users:

```
id (1), name ("Peter")
id (2), name ("Joe")
id (3), name ("Mark")
```

users_projects:

```
id (1), project_id (1), user_id (2)
id (2), project_id (1), user_id (3)
id (3), project_id (2), user_id (1)
id (4), project_id (2), user_id (2)
id (5), project_id (3), user_id (3)
id (6), project_id (3), user_id (1)
```

### My query:

```
SELECT Project.id, User.name
FROM projects AS Project
LEFT JOIN users_projects AS Assignment
    ON Project.id = Assignment.project_id
LEFT JOIN users AS User
    ON User.id = Assignment.user_id
WHERE Project.project_leader_id = 1
    OR Assignment.user_id = 1
```

It should return 3 results but it does not return any results.

The pagination structure is this:

```
$this->paginate = array(
'Project' => array(
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'users_projects', 
            'alias' => 'Assignment',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Assignment.project_id' => 'Project.id',
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Assignment.user_id' => $this->Auth->User('id'),
            'Project.project_leader_id' => $this->Auth->User('id')
        )
    )
));
```

## UPDATE

The query returns only projects containing `Project.project_leader_id` as specified in the WHERE condition and it does not take into account `Assignment.user_id` condition.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN users AS User ON users.id = Assignment.project_id` Shouldn't that be `Assignment.user_id`?

Comment: yes thanks for pointing that out, just so you know the data and names are fake but they symbolize real data

Comment: Not sure if the SQL you posted is what you're trying to do in Cake or what Cake is outputting for the paginate query. If it's what you are trying to do, what is Cake actually outputting?

Comment: @RichardAtHome The SQL is the actual ouput from Cake.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. The 'conditions' clause in the pagination variable under the  'joins' key has to be constructed without the double arrow.

Changing

```
'conditions' => array('Assignment.project_id' => 'Project.id')
```

to

```
'conditions' => array('Assignment.project_id = Project.id')
```

solved the problem.

The initial query looked like this:

```
LEFT JOIN `consultants_assignments` AS `consultantsAssignment` ON
(`consultantsAssignment`.`project_id` = `Project.id`)
```

and after the change:

```
LEFT JOIN `consultants_assignments` AS `consultantsAssignment` ON
(`consultantsAssignment`.`project_id` = `Project`.`id`)
```